# Analytics Core Reporting API suddenly differs heavily from dashboard data

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to get Google Analytics data. So far so good until yesterday, when the data from the created report started to differ from the data on the Analytics dashboard. Previously, all data matched from dashboard and API results without any issues.

So, if my 30-days report (`StartDate = 30daysAgo`, `EndDate = today`) has 118,000 *pageviews* on dashboard, it returns 78,300 on API `batchGet`. Same for my others metrics, `sessions` and `newUsers`.

Everything still wrong even after setting the sample level to `LARGE` and setting the page size to `50000` (v4 allows up to 100,000). It used to work perfectly on `DEFAULT` and `10000`, I can't understand then what is wrong now!

I didn't see any error alert any about quota on *Cloud Platform* project nor on Analytics dashboard. This still in local development environment tho.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cause is sampling. This can be associated with an increase in traffic on the site as a whole.

General thresholds for sampling: 500k sessions **at the property** level for the date range you are using.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192

Sampling level `LARGE` does not mean that sample is 100%.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics?hl=en#sampling

Check fields `samplesReadCounts` and `samplingSpaceSizes` in your Core Reporting API 4 response. If they are empty, sampling hasn't been applied.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData.FIELDS.samples_read_counts

To avoid sampling try to reduce the date range.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I tried changing the `StartDate` to `15daysAgo` but the data still differing. Both `samplesReadCounts` and `samplingSpaceSizes` are `NULL` (using `var_dump( $rows = $report->getData()["samplingSpaceSizes"] )`). This is really strange...

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Hm. Are you sure that dashboard and API report are the same? Any segments, filters? Is GA view the same?

Comment: @ms-easy That's correct, everything still the same. The segment still set as "All users" in both API and dashboard. I didn't change anything, the data just started to differ without any changes. I tried going back a couple days in my code, but still broken.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Check GA views - the same? May be somebody added filter to view, that you use as a source for one of reports. And try to reduce date range more: take 5 days for example, may be sampling even so.